# Create MySQL database from Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

Is it possible to create a MySQL database from Java?

I have only seen connection URLs examples like this where the database name is specified in the URL:

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, "cb0", "xxx" );
```

How can I create a MySQL database when I only have a login name and password?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The database isn't required in the jdbc connection, so you can do something like recommended at http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,99321,102211#msg-102211 and http://marc.info/?l=mysql-java&m=104508605511590&w=2:

```
Conn = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
s=Conn.createStatement();
int Result=s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
```

Answer (score 7):

To create database through Java code, you must use `executeUpdate(sql)` instead of `executeQuery(sql);` and connect to the `mysql` database as root:

```
connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull",
    "root", "root"
);
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate(sql);
st.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

An elegant approach to such issues is using [DDL Utils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/) from Apache. Not only would it serve the basic purpose of allowing to execute your (externally configurable) DDLs, but also would make your application database independent.

Answer (score 1):

To make things even easier, you can use NetBeans 6.5 and it makes setting up SQL databases SO much easier.  I'm using them right now and its a lifesaver on GUI layouts and database connections.  Here's some code on how I connect to mysql database from NetBeans:

```
    //these are variables i declare in the beginning of my code
    public static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jtschema";
    private Connection connection = null;
    public static Statement statement = null;

    public void initSQLServer() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "Dropatrain!248");
                statement = connection.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
                System.out.println("VendorError: " + e.getErrorCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: NetBeans wiki has all the info you need tho set up a sql table in your project also!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lines:

```
    try {
        String databaseName = "dbName";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "yourPassword";

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);

        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE " + databaseName;

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        statement.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, databaseName + " Database has been created successfully", "System Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Pm me your email address so that i can send the JAR file.

Comment: Thanks. But please notice the question was 6 years ago :)