# how to mysqldump on java?

Tags: java, mysql

I made my database in mySQL and I exported it in a file using mysqldump.
Is there a way to make my program on JAVA to connect in mysql and create an empty database with the stracture I saved in the file, only if the above database is not allready exist to the server?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u <username> -p<password> <youdbname> <  <youbackupfile>");
```

you will need to replace `<username>` with your username / `<password>` with your password / `<yourdbname>` with you database name / `<yourbackupfile>` with the file you used for backup

[FAQ for MySQL Backup](http://dev.mysql.com/resources/BackupFAQ.html)

Comment: Thank you.How can I spesify the full path of the backup? I now have it in the same dir that the classes of my netbeans are.

Comment: Replace `< <yourbackupfile>` with `< /full/path/to/your/backup/file` if on not windows and with `< \\full\\path\\to\\your\\backup\\file` if on windows.

Comment: @Vagelism just put the full path where it currently says `<yourbackupfile>`

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysql -u "+username+ " -p "+ password  + "TestDB < "+ 
                                      getClass().getResourceAsStream("File.sql"));

Comment: Please note the spacing / no spacing between the switches and the username / passwords

Comment: After some experiment I show that this command will runn only if the Database is in the server even empty , just the name. But how to do it work with empty sql server that I have access?

Comment: @Vagelism [create the database first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717436/create-mysql-database-from-java) ?