# Why does java process hang executing mysqldump?

Tags: java, mysql, backup

I want to backup database in mysql 5.6.
For this I use this method:

```
public boolean backupDB(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String path) {

        String executeCmd = "D://mysql-5.6.11-win32/bin/mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword
                + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path;
        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {

            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            // any error message?
            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(runtimeProcess.getErrorStream(), "ERR");
            // any output?
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(runtimeProcess.getInputStream(), "OUT");
            // kick them off
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

StreamGobbler is Thread that wraps `runtimeProcess.getErrorStream()` and `runtimeProcess.getInputStream()` into BufferedReader. BufferedReader merely reads line by line using `readLine()` method. This is a hint I got on [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1).

My problem is that method backupDB hangs on this line :

```
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
```

If I substitute waitFor method with exitValue I receive error

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
```

Therefore I must use waitFor method. And unfortunately it runs forever. I must press red icon on eclipse console to stop the JVM.

How to make process complete and backup mysql database?
This is solved thanks!

**EDIT** To launch mysqldump.exe I need to write full path to it :

```
String executeCmd = "D://mysql-5.6.11-win32/bin/mysqldump -u "
```

Don't you know how to get rid of full path. I want to launch mysqldump independently on mysqldump.exe location on computer.

Maybe there is a way to get the path to mysqldump.exe having all connection details.

**EDIT** If I try to use mysqldump without full path to mysqldump.exe I receive this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": CreateProcess error=2, Íå óäàåòñÿ íàéòè óêàçàííûé ôàéë
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at dbViewer.model.ConnectionManager.backupDB(ConnectionManager.java:273)
    at dbViewer.model.ConnectionManager.main(ConnectionManager.java:337)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Íå óäàåòñÿ íàéòè óêàçàííûé ôàéë
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:189)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 5 more
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run the command manually from the commandline?  Does it ask for user input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567699/how-to-mysqldump-on-java

Comment: Ah. You are right it asks me to enter password and after I press Enter indicating no password it successfully creates backup. But I use empty password. How to use empty password to backup database?

Comment: you might be able to pass in a carriage return by writting one to the process's OutputStream

Comment: @dkatzel please tell me how to write carriage return(\n) to OutputStream. I used write('\n') and it does not help. Anyway now I can check if password is empty and if so execute mysqldump without -p option. Thanks, big help!

Comment: It looks like you are using Windows so you may also need a '\r' in there too.  It might be best to write the String returned by String.format("%n").  Depending on the OutputStream you may also need to flush the stream so the Process sees it.

Comment: You can try adding username and password in my.cnf file, that ways it should not prompt you for password.

Comment: @dkatzel,brian and sachin please read my EDIT

Comment: By the way: Exception text means "Не удается найти указанный файл". "File not found" :) Check the path.

Comment: @DRCB Thanks! I want to get rid of path altogether. I want to launch mysqldump.exe without specifying its location on computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use mysqldump *-p* option:

```
mysqldump –u[user name] –p[password] [database name] > [dump file]
```

Comment: PLease look at my first and second EDIT

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Make a new question, you're not supposed to ask too many questions in one question, or edit your question once one question is resolved.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi user "nos" is correct. If my answer was correct and solved your problem you should accept/up-vote it; and then ask a second question. On the particular case you mention, tough, you can't type mysqldump without the full location because the command `mysqldump` is not in your `path`. Google for "set windows path".