# Can not create database jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create a database with java `jdbc` with a method so i'm passing the name type `string` of database as argument to database but i'm facing an issue which is *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Algebra'' at line 1*

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbTest {
private Connection connection;
public void createDb(String name) throws SQLException {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=root");

    String createDbSql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ?";
    PreparedStatement createDbStat = connection.prepareStatement(createDbSql);
    createDbStat.setString(1,name);
    createDbStat.executeUpdate();
}

DbTest() {
    try {
        createDb("Algebra");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DbTest();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `createDbStat.setString(1, name);` it will create a query like this :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'databasename'
//----------------------------^____________^
```

And this is a wrong syntax, the correct should be :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS databasename
```

to solve your problem you can just use :

```
String createDbSql = String.format("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `%s`", name);
//                                                                ^^^^
PreparedStatement createDbStat = connection.prepareStatement(createDbSql);
//createDbStat.setString(1,name); no need for this
createDbStat.executeUpdate();
```

---

### For security reason

Just for security reason, and to avoid SQL Injection make sure that your database name match this:

```
if(name.matches("^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")){
   //Correct name
}
```

for more details read this [Check for valid SQL column name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978062/5558072)

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind your parameter (1) to the database name-
you'll have to use string concatenation in this case.

Your question is also similar to

[How to use a tablename variable for a java prepared statement insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312155/how-to-use-a-tablename-variable-for-a-java-prepared-statement-insert)

and

[CREATE DATABASE query using java jdbc and prepared statement returns syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763214/create-database-query-using-java-jdbc-and-prepared-statement-returns-syntax-erro)