# JDBC No Database selected

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following code in my java class, but I am unable to create a single table, as it wouldn't select a database

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class DBTest {
    // Database credentials
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "1234";

    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        getConnection();
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            createTable(conn);

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            } // nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } // end finally try
        } // end try
        return conn;
    }

    public static void createTable(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Creating database...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        // Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

        // Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION " + "(id INTEGER not NULL, " + " first VARCHAR(255), "
                + " last VARCHAR(255), " + " age INTEGER, " + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
    }

}
```

**Please Note:** The only library, which I have imported is java.sql and that I have got my connector inside my referenced library, so everything should be set up! 
[image]

With all this in mind, can anyone please let me know why I get a **No database selected** SQLException?

Comment: `static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyDatabase";`...

Comment: dont you need jdbc jars?

Comment: @Reimeus thank you for your comment! I know I don't have a database in my url, but how can I create a new one, without having to install any third party software, so that no user, using my program has to install anything either?

Comment: @abtPst I do have the libraries set!

Comment: Your code is hard to follow, for one: why are you creating a new connection to the server (without a database) in `createTable`?

Answer (score 6):

In yours DB_URL variable is missing the name of the Database:

You need just:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db_name`

where `my_db_name` is the name of the Database you created.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The thing is, I do not have a database, and I wanted to create a database from the code, so that whenever someone executes this code, everything which they will create will happen on localhost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717436/create-mysql-database-from-java

Comment: VoodooBiiT, I have not created a dataBase anywhere! This is the main problem I am trying to resolve! How can I create an instance of a database, so that no matter who uses my code, a new database unit will always get created?

Answer (score 2):

You can only create a table if you are connected to a database. Currently you are only connected to the server, so statements like `CREATE TABLE` cannot be executed, as there as nothing to create that table in.

You either need to specify the database in your connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/<database>
```

Or you need to explicitly need to switch to a database using:

```
connection.setCatalog("<database>");
```

From the comments it looks like your actual question is how to create a new database from java, for an answer to that question, you need to look at: [Create MySQL database from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717436/create-mysql-database-from-java).